# How to do something when user clicks on notification on flutter web using firebase messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

I have integrated the firebase_messaging package in my flutter web app. I am able to display notifications both when app is in foregroung or background.

I would now like to open a specific page in my application when the user clicks on the notification. For now, when I click on the notification, the notification is dismissed and nothing happens.

I tried declaring an event handler for the `notificationclick` event, but it never gets triggered.

This is the code in my `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file:

```js
//Code for adding event on click of notification
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    console.log('Notification clicked');
});

importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "..."
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(message) {
    console.log('Received background message ', message);

    const content = JSON.parse(message.data.content);
    const notificationTitle = content.payload.summary ? content.payload.summary : content.payload.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: content.payload.body,
      data: message.data,
    };

    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

And then I send test notifications using Postman like this:

```json
{
    "registration_ids" : ["..."],
    "priority": "high",
    "mutable_content": true,
    "data" : {
        "content": {
            "id": 1,
            "badge": 42,
            "channelKey": "alerts",
            "layout": "BigText",
            "showWhen": true,
            "autoDismissible": true,
            "payload": {
                "redirectTo": "contractDetails",
                "id": "00322860-4a11-11ed-b06b-a77c38cad970",
                "title": "Huston! The eagle has landed!",
                "body": "A small step for a man, but a giant leap to Flutter's community!"
            }
        },
        "actions": [
            {
                "key": "REPLY",
                "label": "Reply",
                "autoDismissible": true,
                "requireInputText": true
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Is there a way to push a route based on the notification payload when the notification is clicked (just like it is possible on android and iOS), or at least to focus my app...?

I've been stuck on this for 5 days now, so any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I have just spent the last 16 hours straight trying to do this as well. The documentation is mucky at best too. There is one page in particular that tells you to add code to index.hml near the top of the page, then again near the bottom of the page... and both code sets are different. Have you been able to figure this out? Oh, and here's that page if you're curious: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages

Comment: I literally just came across this after posting. It looks like an official flutterfire example, where their index.html is extremely different than what they ask you to add. https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/web/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you resolved this your own way, but since I had the same issue, I wanted to post my findings here.

Like me, I am assuming that you were testing in debug mode, on localhost. Further, you were likely using Chrome?

Using Google Chrome, while running on localhost, does not support the "notificationclick" event. This caused me to think that the event was not working in the firebase_messaging package for web. I ended up coding everything in javascript, just to have the same issue on Chrome (localhost). I ended up testing on Edge and it worked.

Due to this, my curiosity sent me to reusing the firebase_messaging package, and here are the results:

- Google Chrome localhost: The event is NOT supported
- Google Chrome in a live: Supported!
- Microsoft Edge localhost: Supported!
- Microsoft Edge live: Supported!
- Mozilla Firefox live mode: Supported!
- Opera live mode: Supported!

When testing Mozilla, I noted that clicking the notification brought the window into the foreground, but my console.log(), within the event listener, did not get printed to the terminal. After a few google searches, I found this to be a common problem with Firefox. The point I wanted to make with this comment, though, was that the Chrome notification (localhost) did NOTHING when clicked; no log, and the window did not come to the foreground. At any rate, this is a browser issue, not a library issue.

With this knowledge, I would assume that all notificationclick events work. If an event is being consumed my another platform, which I have yet to confirm, then platform separated code would be a good option.

If this helps you get your notificationclick working, I have found a resource that may also assist in getting your click actions developed. Links are from same article.

[Displaying a Notification](https://web.dev/push-notifications-display-a-notification/)

[Notification Behavior](https://web.dev/push-notifications-notification-behaviour/)

[Common Notification Patterns](https://web.dev/push-notifications-common-notification-patterns/)

Credit goes to the Authors: Matt Gaunt and Alexey Rodionov